# I want a background inside DIV to be fixed, and only the content to move with scroll, how can I do it?

Tags: css, html, background, styling

As I've already mentioned I want my background to be fixed within it's DIV and only the content to be scrolled.
My problem is that whenever I set the background property to fixed, the background somehow seems to start from the start of the page (0-top) although I've set it only to the div. and it won't be fixed until I start scrolling down.

```
#elections_top
{
    position: relative;
    width: 890px;
    height: auto;
    direction: rtl;
}

#elections_top .elections_news
{
    position: relative;
    width: 890px;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
    background: url("../images/coca_cola_bg.jpg") #e01b22;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:50% top; 
}
```

elections_news is relative to elections_top, it comes after a header in the site, and the background somehow seems to be placed starting from the header

Comment: Please share your HTML & CSS code.

Comment: You can't (and please don't) just give a link, you must provide some code which doesn't work :) See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: please check the added code above

Comment: Your code seems to be working.. I don't see what's wrong.. http://jsfiddle.net/P8MzR/

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove  `background-attachment:fixed;`

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll within the contents of a div, the background will remain fixed when you add

`background-attachment:fixed;`.

You cannot control the background scrolling af a div, when you acre scroling inside another div.

In the link which you have given, the background is a div having the size 100% by 100% and the div which scrolls is a sub-div which has a height more than the height of the parent-div. The parent div has the `background-attachment:fixed;` property and the sub-div just scrolls normally.

Hope this helps.